# How do you change Tor Circuit For Site using javascript via Tampermonkey?

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, tor

In Tor Browser, I can set "New Tor Circuit for site". You can also do this by pressing ctrl+shift+L.

I have installed Tampermonkey-Addon in Tor Browser and was thinking, maybe it is possible to simulate these key presses ctrl+shift+L to achieve that? Or will this not work? Do you have any better ideas? I hope the question is clear!

---

I'm forced to write an answer here because I'm being accused of not having tried anything (see the comments). My following code is simulating the key presses ctrl+shift+L every 10th second which are the keys we humans press to request a new tor circuit. **However this is not working and I don't know why.** I guess my code is not working for my problem because these are only simulated key presses.

```
setInterval(function() {
  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    ctrlKey: true,
    shiftKey: true,
    key: 'l'
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Have you researched how to emulate key presses using Tampermonkey? If not, please do this and then try the suggestions. The question is clear, but it tells us you haven't tried anything. Tell and show us what you've done and we'll have a better idea what to suggest for the resolution.

Comment: @tenepolis Additional information should be added to the question - not posted as an answer. I've done that for you this time.